# Selective listing (ls) of files

Tags: ls, negate

I have a list of files like:
(in general, it's of the format `/data/logs/var_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.log`)

```
/data/logs/var_20121002103531.log
/data/logs/var_20121002104215.log
/data/logs/var_20121002120001.log
```

I've tried in vain to list all the files which DO NOT have 12 as HH.
i.e. input:

```
/data/logs/var_20121002103531.log
/data/logs/var_20121002104215.log
/data/logs/var_20121002120001.log  # THIS IS TO BE OMITTED
/data/logs/var_20121002140001.log
```

Required Output:

```
/data/logs/var_20121002103531.log
/data/logs/var_20121002104215.log
/data/logs/var_20121002140001.log
```

I tried

```
ls -1tr /data/logs/var_20121002^[12]
ls -1tr /data/logs/var_20121002![11]
```

but, not getting what i expect.

Can someone please pinpoint where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Happy that i got it myself.. :)

Comment: solution: ls -ltr /data/logs/var_20121002* | grep -v 2012100212